# why Lapack routine dgesv doesn't solve this?

Tags: r, matrix-factorization

Suppose I have the following 3 by 3 matrix:

```
p<-3
X<-matrix(1/p,p,p)
```

--$\pmb X$ is just a $p$ by $p$ matrix where every entry is $1/p$.
Now I want to solve the system

$$\pmb a\pmb X=\pmb 1_p$$

where $\pmb 1_p$ is a vector of 1 of length $p$.
I know $\pmb 1_p$ is the solution to such a system, 
but when I do, in `R`,

```
solve(X,rep(1,p))
```

I get

```
Error in solve.default(X, rep(1, p)) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[2,2] = 0
```

instead of $\pmb 1_p$. My question is why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your matrix does not have an inverse, which is why `dgesv` returns an error.

Comment: thanks, but are you implying that dgesv computes $\pmb X^{-1}$?

Comment: At the level of abstraction I wish to discuss this problem, yes. We could get into more technical details, but for what you're asking, they seem irrelevant. `solve` in R is computing something like an inverse, and the algorithm will progress to a point where it has to divide by zero, which is usually ill-defined, so the program throws an error.

Comment: [netlib dgesv](http://www.netlib.no/netlib/lapack/double/dgesv.f) is rather explicit in what happens. A pivoted LU decomposition is computed, which requires a regular matrix as input.